# Basic 2D Lighting Optimization Issue in Fragment Shader with OpenGL (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, optimization

I'm using a fragment shader to implement 2D lighting (code further below). Even though I am satisfied with the visuals of the light i noticed that it has a quite big GPU usage, and when trying to add about 40+ light sources the usage is close to 100% (GTX 1050).

I have a uniform array of structs that contain data about each light source and for loop that goes through all of them.

At first I thought I was pushing too much data to the GPU so I combined the RGB values of the light color in a single 32 bit integer and the two strengths of the light in a single 32 bit integer as well. Then I tried simplifying the formulas I used (using a composed, by composed I'm not referring to the operation, function from multiple linear functions) but it seemed that just made the matters worse.

I think it's worth noting the difference between `LightStrength` and `VisualStrength` values that I used in the code, the `LightStrength` is the strength of the light that lights up the medium around it and the `VisualStrength` is the strength of the colored hue around the light. And there is also a dark hue variable that is used to make the scene darker as of in the different times of the day.

The code of the fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

in vec2 texCoord0;
uniform vec3 CameraPosition;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform float DarkHue;

uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

struct LightSource {
    vec2 Position;
    int LightColor;
    int ArgumentValue;
};

uniform LightSource LightSources[300];
uniform int LightSourceCount;

float GetLightfactor(float x,float Streght) {
    return min(1/(x*(Streght/100.0)+1),1);
}

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture,texCoord0);

    vec3 LightSum = vec3(0);
    vec4 PCameraPosition = vec4(CameraPosition,0) * Projection;

    vec2 NormalizedPosition = gl_FragCoord.xy*2/u_resolution-1;

    float LightFactor,VisualFactor,LightStreght,VisualStreght;

    for (int i = 0;i < LightSourceCount;++i) {

        vec4 Pos = vec4(LightSources[i].Position,0,0) * Projection + PCameraPosition; 

        vec2 coord = (NormalizedPosition-Pos.xy) * u_resolution;
        LightFactor = 0.0;
        VisualFactor = 0.0;

        LightStreght = LightSources[i].ArgumentValue & 0xffff;
        VisualStreght = (LightSources[i].ArgumentValue >> 16) & 0xffff;

        float lng = length(coord);

        LightFactor = GetLightfactor(lng,LightStreght);
        VisualFactor = GetLightfactor(lng,VisualStreght);

        LightSum = mix(LightSum,vec3(1),gl_FragColor.rgb * LightFactor * (1-DarkHue)) + vec3(((LightSources[i].LightColor >> 16)&0xff)/255.0,((LightSources[i].LightColor >> 8)&0xff)/255.0,(LightSources[i].LightColor&0xff)/255.0) * VisualFactor;

    }

    gl_FragColor.rgb *= DarkHue;
    gl_FragColor.rgb += LightSum;
    
}
```

The code of the c++ function that adds a light source. (Yes when setting uniforms caching is used)

````cpp
static void AddLightSource(Vec2 Position, uint8_t R, uint8_t B, uint8_t G, uint16_t LightStrenght,uint16_t VisualStrenght) {
        std::string access = "LightSources[" + std::to_string(ActiveLightSources) + "]";
        int Value = (VisualStrenght << 16) | LightStrenght;
        int Color = (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
        Vec3 Translated = VertexArrayManager::TranslateValue;
        shader->setUniform2f(access + ".Position", glm::vec2(Position.x+Translated.x,Position.y + Translated.y));
        shader->setUniform1i(access + ".LightColor", Color);
        shader->setUniform1i(access + ".ArgumentValue", Value);
        ActiveLightSources++;
        shader->setUniform1i("LightSourceCount", ActiveLightSources);
}
```
````

Comment: It looks like you've written a forward renderer. These are known to scale quite poorly as the number of lights increases. Have you looked into deferred or forward+ rendering (effectively, forward rendering with tile-based optimizations via compute shaders)? These approaches are designed to have much better performance when there are many lights that affect only part of the view.

Comment: I looked up the methods you suggested and it looks like it will solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @BananaFructa IMHO the best way to thank DMGregory is to eventually post an answer with some of your findings and/or a link to the code if open.

Comment: I will once i eventually implement it and get it working.